# export relational model from Oracle sql developer to Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I found JDBC driver for connection to Postgresql database, but how to export script from relational model?

Comment: Have a look at ora2pg or ora_migrator.

Comment: I wanted some easy tool. These tools doesn't have even executables....

Comment: Migration from Oracle to PostgreSQL is not easy, sorry. But it is worth the trouble.

Comment: did you build a model? there's a 'Generate DDL' button on the main toolbar. We won't generate Postresql SQL, but a generic ansi SQL, that would probably work in your environment.